# Installing and using client side templating engines

Tags: handlebars.js, dust.js, client-side-templating

I am in the process of building a database website. I am currently constructing the various webpages. For my search results, I would like to use a client side templating engine. I have not used one before and have a quick question:

I see that many of the templating engines (I have researched Handlebars.js and dust.js the most) need to be installed on the command line (as opposed to simply included as a library like jQuery). While I am currently developing on a mac using MAMP and can install them locally, does this mean I would also need to install it on the public server the webapp will sit on when live?

I have wondered whether the installation is necessary for the compiler and you then simply upload pre-compiled templates that require no extra code/installation.

If anyone could clarify, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to install the template engine locally to be able to use them. Actually, using template engines in the client can be done in 2 different ways, the far I know:

**On-the-fly compiling and rendering**
You download the plain template file (`.hbs`, `.dust`, `.mustache`, etc) via AJAX *or* put them in the middle of your HTML, like using `<script type="text/template">...</script>`
Then, you pass it to the engine's `compile()` and `render()` functions. The engine `.js` file needs to be included in your page.

This is good for when you're development environment, but bad for production cases.

**Pre-compiled templates and then rendering**
You download the pre-compiled template (an `.js` file with a function which will return the HTML) via AJAX and then call your engine's `render()` function.
This is the opposite of the above technique, and would require you to have the engine lib installed in some way locally, to allow you to pre-compile them before going to production.

Also, you *may not* need to include the engine lib in your page, depending on how the engine compiles your template.